# remount read-only with deleted file descriptors: Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, mount, file-descriptor

I need to update a running daemon on a read-only mounted ext4 file system. The device has been remounted read-write, if I modify the daemon (mv, cp), the process keeps running, but the file descriptor changes its state to "deleted".

Now, it is not possible to remount the file system read-only anymore (device or resource busy), until the daemon process has been killed and the descriptor has been freed.

Is there a way to keep the file descriptor valid while modifying the binary of a running process?

Comment: using ``find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep deleted`` and then cat'ing something into it might help

Comment: To be sure: the file descriptor you are talking about is the binary executable of the daemon?

Comment: It is a binary executable, I do have all information about process id, descriptor id, but I don't know how to access a deleted descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If the process opened a file for reading from a read-only filesystem, the filesystem is remounted read-write and file is removed, then you have an opened file descriptor to a deleted file. The process still has access to the original contents of the file, but Linux somehow treats this as reason for not allowing remount to read-only again.

You will be fine if the original binary is not removed, only new contents written to it. Calling 'cp new-binary old-binary' will not prevent remount to read-only. Also 'cat new-binary >old-binary' will be safe. 
But you will experience "mount: /somepath is busy" error if you upgrade the binary with 'mv new-binary old-binary' or 'rm old-binary; cp new-binary old-binary'.